# JavaFX ScrollPane update of viewportBoundsProperty

Tags: javafx, scrollpane

I am building a tilemap just like openstreetmap or google map using JavaFX with a ScrollPane and a TilePane.

In the tilemap, we need to only load the currently visible portion of the screen and not all the tiles.

It seems like JavaFX ScrollPane updates its `viewportBounds` `MinX`, `MaxX` and `MinY` and `MaxY` (*let's call it `offset` for the rest of the question*) :

- while panning using a mouse interaction (click and drag).
- but **not when panning using the vertical and horizontal scroll bars or when using a touchpad**.

This is a problem because it means that I can compute the currently visible portion of my content while clicking and draging but not when using the scrollbars or moving using the touchpad.

I need to get this offset constantly because my ScrollPane's content is loaded when it is currently visible at the ScrollPane "position" :

Here is a minimal reproductible example illustrating the situation :

```java
public class DemoScrollPane extends javafx.application.Application {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoScrollPane.class);


    public static void run(String[] args) {
        javafx.application.Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // create content
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(1000,1000, Color.AQUA);
        Rectangle rectangleInitialVP = new Rectangle(640,480, Color.GRAY);
        pane.getChildren().add(rectangle);
        pane.getChildren().add(rectangleInitialVP);

        // create scrollPane
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setContent(pane);
        // add click and drag interaction
        scrollPane.setPannable(true);

        // register a watcher on scrollPane viewportBoundsProperty
        InvalidationListener listener =
                    o -> {
                        logger.debug("viewport change {}",scrollPane.getViewportBounds());
                    };
        // This is triggered when moving using click and drag (pan)
        // and does correctly update the scrollPane viewportbounds.        
        // BUT this is not trigered when moving by clocking on hbar or vbar or by using a touchpad (on mac) without clicking.
        scrollPane.viewportBoundsProperty().addListener(listener);

        // display the app
        Scene scene = new Scene(scrollPane, 640, 480);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        logger.debug("stop");
    }
}
```

Can someone provide me with pointers on how to compute (or get) this offset dynamically on any scroll action (click and drag panning or panning using a touchpad or using horizontal or vertical bars) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post a [mre] demonstrating the issue

Comment: That's a bit weird. I don't understand why the viewport bounds are changing at all; they are just the bounds of the viewport in the scroll pane itself (at least, as I understand it). They should only change if the scroll pane actually changes size, or if a scroll bar is hidden or shown.  It looks like the panning is implementing scrolling differently (via a translation on the viewport?), for some reason. It's not clear why you need the viewport bounds, though.

Comment: @James_D I did update the question with a simple and replicable example

Comment: Well It felt natural that the viewport while paning would not change its width and height but its minX, maxX minY maxY as the "window" through witch we view the content is moving around. Also as you state, this is implemented this way for click and drag panning, and also in other graphic frameworks (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#pos-prop)

Comment: Why would the viewport's `minX`, etc., change? It is not moving.

Comment: well it is "scrolling" on a larger content, so relatively to the displayed content the viewport is moving?

Comment: Also did you run the sample I provided ? how do you explain that the behaviour I described seems to be implemented for some interactions and not for other ? Is there a misusage somewhere in my initialization code ? I am working on debian linux and MacOS M1.

Comment: The viewport is not moving relative to the scroll pane. I'm not sure what picture you have in your mind, but as you scroll, the scroll pane and the "window" (viewport) into the content stay in exactly the same place. The content itself moves behind the viewport.

Comment: Yes, I did run the example. As I said in that comment: "it is weird" (i.e. doesn't make sense) and "it looks like panning is implementing scrolling differently". Why do you need this anyway? Surely it's enough to just know when scrolling has occured?

Comment: Alright nice, so if I need to retrieve the content's offset should I focus on the content's position ? If you are exert enough with this kind of subject do you think you can come up with a psoeudo code that logs the position offset in real time, while panning ?

Comment: Why don't you just set the `hmax` and `vmax` to the size of the content? Then the `hvalue` and `vvalue` give you exactly what you need.

Comment: Also if the behaviour you describe is supposed to be implemented does it mean that there is a bug in the click/drag panning interaction ? It does modify minX maxX minY and maxY.

Comment: That behavior isn't really specified, so I'm not sure it can be classified as a bug. But it's certainly not behavior I'd expect.

Comment: Also going in JavaFX code I've seen that the place where this viewPort is updated is in its skin, in the layout(...) function. On layout request these minX maxX, minY and maxY are updated correctly. 

As for why I need it : it is to implement a tilemap. The content is the tilemap and tiles are loaded and recycled depending on their visibility. Thus I need to know what the scrollPane "views" of its content to be able to load/unload the correct tiles.

Comment: But that’s not determined by the location of the viewport within the scroll pane. All you need is the scrolling offset and the width/height of the viewport (which don’t actually change in your example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer of your question about the difference is :: **that's how it is implemented !!**

Firstly, the viewPort bounds are updated everytime the scrollPane tries to layout its children. The sneak peak of layoutChildren method in ScrollPaneSkin class is as below:

```
protected void layoutChildren(double x, double y, double w, double h) {
  ScrollPane control = (ScrollPane)this.getSkinnable();
  ... // All the stuff for layouting
  ...
  control.setViewportBounds(new BoundingBox(this.snapPosition(this.viewContent.getLayoutX()), this.snapPosition(this.viewContent.getLayoutY()), this.snapSize(this.contentWidth), this.snapSize(this.contentHeight)));
}
```

Now if we check for the related implementation for "pannable" property of ScrollPane, the code is as below (in ScrollPaneSkin class):

```
this.viewRect.setOnDragDetected((e) -> {
    if (IS_TOUCH_SUPPORTED) {
        this.startSBReleasedAnimation();
    }

    if (((ScrollPane)this.getSkinnable()).isPannable()) {
        this.dragDetected = true;
        if (this.saveCursor == null) {
            this.saveCursor = ((ScrollPane)this.getSkinnable()).getCursor();
            if (this.saveCursor == null) {
                this.saveCursor = Cursor.DEFAULT;
            }

            ((ScrollPane)this.getSkinnable()).setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
            ((ScrollPane)this.getSkinnable()).requestLayout(); // !! THIS LINE !!
        }
    }

});
this.viewRect.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, (e) -> {
    this.mouseDown = false;
    if (this.dragDetected) {
        if (this.saveCursor != null) {
            ((ScrollPane)this.getSkinnable()).setCursor(this.saveCursor);
            this.saveCursor = null;
            ((ScrollPane)this.getSkinnable()).requestLayout();// !! THIS LINE !!
        }

        this.dragDetected = false;
    }

    if ((this.posY > ((ScrollPane)this.getSkinnable()).getVmax() || this.posY < ((ScrollPane)this.getSkinnable()).getVmin() || this.posX > ((ScrollPane)this.getSkinnable()).getHmax() || this.posX < ((ScrollPane)this.getSkinnable()).getHmin()) && !this.touchDetected) {
        this.startContentsToViewport();
    }

});
```

From the above code you can notice that, when the "pannable" property is true, if a drag is detected, it will request a layout. And in the next scene pulse it will call the layoutChildren and will update the viewportBounds. And the same thing happens when you release the mouse (if a drag is detected). That is the reason you can see the logs only at the start and end of the panning and not while dragging.

Now coming to the code of hbar/vbar dragging, the code when the scrollBar value is updated is as below: (in ScrollPaneSkin class)

```
InvalidationListener vsbListener = (valueModel) -> {
    if (!IS_TOUCH_SUPPORTED) {
        this.posY = Utils.clamp(((ScrollPane)this.getSkinnable()).getVmin(), this.vsb.getValue(), ((ScrollPane)this.getSkinnable()).getVmax());
    } else {
        this.posY = this.vsb.getValue();
    }

    this.updatePosY();
};
this.vsb.valueProperty().addListener(vsbListener);
InvalidationListener hsbListener = (valueModel) -> {
    if (!IS_TOUCH_SUPPORTED) {
        this.posX = Utils.clamp(((ScrollPane)this.getSkinnable()).getHmin(), this.hsb.getValue(), ((ScrollPane)this.getSkinnable()).getHmax());
    } else {
        this.posX = this.hsb.getValue();
    }

    this.updatePosX();
};
this.hsb.valueProperty().addListener(hsbListener);
```

The value listeners just update the layoutX/Y property of the viewContent but not a layout request. The updatePosX method is as below:

```
private double updatePosX() {
    ScrollPane sp = (ScrollPane)this.getSkinnable();
    double x = this.isReverseNodeOrientation() ? this.hsb.getMax() - (this.posX - this.hsb.getMin()) : this.posX;
    double minX = Math.min(-x / (this.hsb.getMax() - this.hsb.getMin()) * (this.nodeWidth - this.contentWidth), 0.0D);
    this.viewContent.setLayoutX(this.snapPosition(minX));
    if (!sp.hvalueProperty().isBound()) {
        sp.setHvalue(Utils.clamp(sp.getHmin(), this.posX, sp.getHmax()));
    }

    return this.posX;
}
```

**Another Solution:**

+1 for @James_D answer. If you want to keep this more dynamic or if you dont know ahead the max bounds of your pane, you can try the below approach.

From the above code, we can notice that whether we pan or drag the scroll bar, the layoutX/Y properties of the viewContent(scrollPane's content parent node) are updated. So you can add listener to its layoutX/Y properties which will give you the exact position without the need of setting the min/max values to scroll bars.

```
ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
scrollPane.setContent(pane);
scrollPane.getContent().parentProperty().addListener((obs, old, viewContent) -> {
    if (viewContent != null) {
        InvalidationListener posListener = e -> {
            double x = viewContent.getLayoutX() * -1;
            double y = viewContent.getLayoutY() * -1;
            double width = scrollPane.getViewportBounds().getWidth();
            double height = scrollPane.getViewportBounds().getHeight();
            Bounds movingViewPort = new BoundingBox(x, y, width, height);
            System.out.println("viewport: " + movingViewPort);
        };
        viewContent.layoutXProperty().addListener(posListener);
        viewContent.layoutYProperty().addListener(posListener);
    }
});
scrollPane.setPannable(true);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sai I was going to describe it myself but I wanted to understand the `why` of that design. Thanks for your complete answer and proposal. Looking at SO questions about JavaFX ScrollPane it seems like this is the kind of subject that comes to the table reasonably often.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @James_D's comment here is a solution that goes around the problem (see below).

If someone has a better understanding of JavaFX's `ScrollPane` do not hesitate to explain difference between

- the click and scroll that updates the viewPort of the `ScrollPane`
- vs scroll with H and V bars that does not update the viewPort of the `ScrollPane`.

Here is the solution taken from from James_D's comment :

```java
public class DemoScrollPane extends javafx.application.Application {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoScrollPane.class);


    public static void run(String[] args) {
        javafx.application.Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // create content
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setMaxSize(1000,1000);
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(1000,1000, Color.AQUA);
        Rectangle rectangleInitialVP = new Rectangle(640,480, Color.GRAY);
        pane.getChildren().add(rectangle);
        pane.getChildren().add(rectangleInitialVP);


        // create scrollPane
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setContent(pane);
        scrollPane.setVmin(0);
        scrollPane.setVmax(pane.getMaxHeight());
        scrollPane.setHmin(0);
        scrollPane.setHmax(pane.getMaxWidth());
        
        // add click and drag interaction
        scrollPane.setPannable(true);

        // register a watcher on scrollPane viewportBoundsProperty
        InvalidationListener listener =
                    o -> {
            Bounds movingViewPort = new BoundingBox(scrollPane.getHvalue(),
                    scrollPane.getVvalue(),
                    0.,
                    scrollPane.getViewportBounds().getWidth(),
                    scrollPane.getViewportBounds().getHeight(),
                    0.
                    );
                        logger.debug("viewport {}",movingViewPort);
                    };
        // This is triggered when moving using click and drag (pan)
        // and does correctly update the scrollPane viewportbounds.

        // BUT this is not trigered when moving by clocking on hbar or vbar or by using a touchpad (on mac)
        // without clicking.
        // (even tough the viewport obviously change)
        scrollPane.vvalueProperty().addListener(listener);
        scrollPane.hvalueProperty().addListener(listener);

        // display the app
        Scene scene = new Scene(scrollPane, 640, 480);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        logger.debug("stop");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are still completely misunderstanding what the viewport is: *"(even tough the viewport obviously change)"*. The viewport is not changing.